# How to upload files to the "SuiteScripts" folder from Netsuite IDE (Eclipse)

Tags: ide, directory, netsuite

I am fairly new to NetSuite and NetSuite scripting. My company has several dozen script files already in the NetSuite File Cabinet, under the default SuiteScripts folder. Also, I am using the SuiteCloud IDE, which is just basically Eclipse with a NetSuite plugin. This way I can download all of the scripts into a single SuiteCloud IDE project, work on them locally, and then upload them back to the server for testing.

When you create a new NetSuite project, one of the project settings is File Cabinet Folder. This defaults to a subdirectory  under "SuiteScripts" with the same name as your project. For example, if your project is called "MyScripts", the default will be SuiteScripts/MyScripts. You can of course change this, but it is impossible to just specify the SuiteScripts folder alone, as I get an error saying "File Cabinet folder must have 2 segments." However, the existing scripts all live under SuiteScripts (no subdirectory). Any file that I upload to the server, whether it be a new file that I created locally or even a previously downloaded file that already exists in the File Cabinet, will end up in SuiteScripts/MyScripts. This can be hugely problematic, causing dupes and all kinds of other nastiness. Anyone have any experience with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NetSuite has decided to limit the uploading functionality to subfolders of SuiteScripts. If I had to guess, their intention there is to force you to place your scripting projects in their own folders so that the SuiteScripts folder itself does not get cluttered with scripts.

You can specify a subfolder of SuiteScripts with any name; it does not have to be the name of your Eclipse project. You have a couple options, depending on how you want your files to be organized in Eclipse and in the File Cabinet.

The way we typically do it is to create a single folder that will house *all* of our scripts, call it `SuiteScripts/Projects/`. In the file cabinet, we create this `Projects` folder under `SuiteScripts`. In Eclipse's NetSuite Project Settings, we map our Eclipse project to `SuiteScripts/Projects`. In our Eclipse project, we group related source files logically into folders, like `iPad Integration` or `Approval Process`. Then we upload to the File Cabinet, and now we have a nice folder structure of organized scripts, something like:

```
SuiteScripts
    Projects
        iPad Application
            iPadScript.js
            iPadRESTlet.js
        Approval Process
            SalesOrderApproval.js
            PurchaseOrderApproval.js
```

We have much more detailed naming standards for our files, but you get the picture.

My recommendation is to create a new folder in your SuiteScripts folder and move all existing scripts into there using the File Cabinet's "Move" button. Then, map your SuiteCloud Project to that new folder and upload/download as needed.

Comment: I had thought about doing something similar to this. However I was worried that moving the existing scripts might break current functionality. As I said we have a bunch of existing, functioning scripts that are referenced from forms today. Is NetSuite smart enough to find scripts that have been moved without my having to go into the form definitions and point to the new location?

Comment: Yes, if you move a source file in the File Cabinet using the Move button in NetSuite, the Script records will still know where to find that file. They do not reference the file by path, but rather by internal ID, which does not change when you move the file.

Comment: Although it may seem obvious to others, this answer helped me to realize that certain folders will not appear if Folder permissions are not set correctly.  I was confused why I could not access import any files at all and it initially appeared that the IDE was failing to talk to NetSuite but actually NetSuite was returning nothing because only the SuiteScripts folder was being looked at and that folder was restricted.  So, in summary, the SuiteCloud IDE does not tell you when this folder is hidden due to permissions even if the GUI will show the same user a "SuiteScripts" menu option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the erictgrubaugh's solution and I've been following stoic software's tutorials. But steavepoll if you want to change it for only one script then you can follow these steps:

1. Create new SuiteCloud Project under the same folder which you are targeting
2. Edit into mainfest.xml file(right click->NetSuite->Add Dependency References to Manifest)
3. Validate Project against Account
4. Deploy

It worked in my case